# SQL Server Update based on compare date with current date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I've a table as below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblProduct](
    [PrdId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PrdName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DOE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tblProduct] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PrdId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tblProduct] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblProduct_UpdatedDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [UpdatedDate]
GO
```

and it has data as below

```
+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| PrdId | PrdName  | IsActive |           DOE           |       UpdatedDate       |
+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|     1 | Product1 |        0 | 2020-05-11 10:29:26.710 | 2020-05-11 10:29:36.523 |
|     2 | Product2 |        1 | 2020-05-11 10:29:26.710 | 2020-05-11 10:30:12.467 |
+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

My output should be

```
+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| PrdId | PrdName  | IsActive |           DOE           |       UpdatedDate       |
+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|     1 | Product1 |        1 | 2020-05-11 10:29:26.710 | 2020-05-11 10:29:36.523 |
|     2 | Product2 |        0 | 2020-05-11 10:29:26.710 | 2020-05-11 10:30:12.467 |
+-------+----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

my need is I want to update IsActive column based on DOE (Date of expiry) with current date
for eg. if DOE = Current date and if IsActive = False  then update IsActive = true
similarly if DOE = Current date and if IsActive = True then update IsActive = false

In order to acheive this I've created a stored procedure with 2 update statement but it is not giving correct result. My stored procedure is as below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProdcutActivationInActivation]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Update [tblProduct] set is_active= 1 where cast(DOE  as date) = cast(GETDATE() as date) 

    Update [tblProduct] set is_active= 0 where cast(DOE  as date) = cast(GETDATE() as date) 
END    
GO
```

Comment: You say "but it is not giving correct result" - what is the result and what is not correct about it?

Answer (score 0):

Well your where is missing the second part of your condition, and isactive=0 or 1 for each case, however i find the date comparision odd, Date of expiration it means that if today < to DOE it will be active right? it hasn't expired, and if today >= DOE it is expired, so you need something like this

```
Update [tblProduct] set is_active= 0 where cast(GETDATE() as date) >= cast(DOE  as date) and is_active=1

Update [tblProduct] set is_active= 1 where cast(GETDATE() as date) < cast(DOE  as date) and is_active=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CASE Expression:

```
UPDATE [TBLPRODUCT] 
SET Is_Active= CASE WHEN  CAST(GETDATE() as date) = CAST(DOE  as date) AND Is_active=1 THEN 0
               WHEN  CAST(GETDATE() as date) = cast(DOE  as date) AND Is_active=0 THEN 1 END
```

Comment: Thiyagu, Thanks a lot for your solution, its working but if we have more records its updating Other IsActive records to NULL...it should not update other records. Could you test this

Comment: Those Records(Updated as NULL) are does not Satisfy these Condtions. You can add a Else Part for those before the END Statement--@rajeshnrh

Comment: Thanks thepanch for your great support, yours script also working fine.

Comment: Thiyagu, in the table I've UpdatedDate, it is set with GetDate() by default, now when I use your update query is it possible to update this UpdatedDate also ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by adding a comma after the END, and The Column name('UpdatedDate') = here the Value ; What Should you need to UPDATE --@rajeshnrh